# How to use jspdf in one page application angularjs

Tags: angularjs, jspdf

I have a one page application in angular.
To create a PDF page from the HTML content I using ***jsPDF*** library.
In the index page there is a function that create PDF from this div:
**(notice, this is a ng-view div)**

**The div**

```
<div id="doPDF" ng-view></div>
```

But it is not successful.

**the error**

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The Js code

```
 $scope.createPDF=function(){
      var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4')
      , source = $('#doPdf')[0]
      , specialElementHandlers = {

         '#aaa': function(element, renderer){
         return true
         }
      }

      margins = {
         top: 80,
         bottom: 60,
         left: 40,
         width: 522
      };

      pdf.fromHTML(
         source // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
         , margins.left // x coord
         , margins.top // y coord
         , {
           'width': margins.width // max width of content on PDF
         , 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
         },
         function (dispose) {
            pdf.save('Test.pdf');
         },
         margins
         )

    }
```

(In other div-s the DPF generator function work without problem.)
**What can I do to generate PDF page from ng-view?

(I want one function that work from the index page and take the content from the ng-view.)**

Comment: Include js code too please

Comment: you are using JQuery to access elements rendered by AngularJS. That doesn't work. You need a tool like PhantomJS or Grunt.

Comment: What the way to do it with them? (PhantomJS or Grunt)